# Using javascript on wordpress site to add/modify a link

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I currently have an html page where I use javascript to add a link to a different port on the same host, as in the code below.

If I'm on a machine with address `192.168.1.10:8090` the link provided is `192.168.1.10:5000`

I'm trying to the same function to a wordpress site, but can't work out how to add javascript and add a link to the page (or reference an existing link).

I've not used wordpress before, so grateful for any help with this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="ext_link" style="text-align:center"> 
      <script>
          window.onload = function(){
              var x = location.hostname;
              var init = "http://";
              var link_stem = x.concat(':5000');
              var link_address = init.concat(link_stem);
              console.log(link_address);
              var a = document.createElement('a');
              var linkText = document.createTextNode("Link to Port 5000");
              a.appendChild(linkText);
              a.title = "LinkToPort5000";
              a.href = link_address;
              document.getElementById("ext_link").appendChild(a);
              };
      </script>
    </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```